Nvdia Quadro GP100 on Ubuntu 22.04
Edit : I found this saying the GP100 is certified for Ubuntu 20.04, but could not find a similar page for 22.04. Do I need to switch to 20.04 to use my GP100s?
I got a new pc, and am having troubles getting my extra graphics cards to be detected bys PyTorch and nvidia-smi. I've looked around and can't find articles with the same issue
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04
I have a 4060 ti and two Quadro GP100s connected by a NVLink bridge
nvidia-smi detects my 4060 just fine and it outputs graphics, but not the quadros. lspci detects the quadros though, so they seem to be registered by the system.
The nvidia driver installed is 560.35.03, which Nvidia says supports the GP100s.
Does anyone know how to fix this? Is this somehow due to the NVlink bridge? Is there other software I need to install?
I set up my drivers automatically with
   sudo ubuntu-drivers install

and I installed the cuda toolkit with
    sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit

Below is the output of nvidia-smi
  +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  | NVIDIA-SMI 560.35.03              Driver Version: 560.35.03      CUDA Version: 12.6     |
  |-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
  | GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
  | Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
  |                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
  |=========================================+========================+======================|
  |   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060 Ti     Off |   00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
  |  0%   38C    P8             10W /  160W |     446MiB /   8188MiB |     14%      Default |
  |                                         |                        |                  N/A |
  +-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                           
  +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  | Processes:                                                                              |
  |  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
  |        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
  |=========================================================================================|
  |    0   N/A  N/A      1675      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            294MiB |
  |    0   N/A  N/A      1952      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                           97MiB |
  +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


   

